# Spring Cloud Task can not wok on SCDF Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-cloud-task

i use SCDF Kubernetes Server to deploy the Spring Cloud Task. When i launch the Spring Cloud Task on SCDF Kubernetes Server,i find two strange problems, see below detail:

1. when deploying the Spring Cloud Task,the Pod with arguments will be produced on Kubernetes,[see Pod picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IGDMg.jpg). the problem is that arguments of the Pod can not pass to the Spring Cloud Task.
2. when i launch the Spring Cloud Task,if i want to add some properties that the format is app.mytask.test=aaa,i find the property can not pass to Spring Cloud Task, and even override all arguments.

am i missing something?,or bugs? please give me some advises, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why do you think the arguments are not passed to the task app? It works fine for me. I created a simple task that just prints the args:

```
dataflow:>app register --type task --name hello --uri docker://dturanski/hello-world-task:v2
dataflow:>task create --name hello --definition "hello"
dataflow:>task launch hello --arguments "app.mytesk.test=aaa"
```

The log file:

```
Starting: TaskExecution{executionId=5, parentExecutionId=null, exitCode=null, taskName='hello', startTime=Sat Oct 14 21:21:42 GMT 2017, endTime=null, exitMessage='null', externalExecutionId='null', errorMessage='null', arguments=[--spring.datasource.username=root,spring.cloud.task.name=hello, spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://10.59.251.149:3306/dataflow, -spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver, --spring.datasource.password=srz427UgQ0, app.mytesk.test=aaa, -spring.cloud.task.executionid=5]}
arg: --spring.datasource.username=root
arg: --spring.cloud.task.name=hello
arg: --spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://10.59.251.149:3306/dataflow
arg: --spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver
arg: --spring.datasource.password=srz427UgQ0
arg: app.mytesk.test=aaa
arg: --spring.cloud.task.executionid=5
```

Actually, the args are already shown in the standard `Starting: TaskExecution`  message.

Comment: I use SCDF kubernetes Server to deploy the task app,environment variables can be shown in the task app,but arguments can not be shown,then, i print the content of ApplicationArguments in the task app,i find it is empty

Comment: if i change spring.cloud.deployer.kubernetes.entryPointStyle=shell,the properties will be passed in through Environment Variables,and shown in the task app.

Comment: if i use SCDF Local Server, it is no problem for this.